# Call function in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, function

I am a new iPhone developer and I am practicing about call function in Objective-C language. Could someone can help me? There are my program details. Thank you!

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestingProgramViewController : UIViewController{
    NSTimer *aTimer;
    id getPic;
}
@end

#import "TestingProgramViewController.h"

@interface TestingProgramViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *testingPic;
@end

@implementation TestingProgramViewController

- (void) obtainPic:(NSString *)picName{
    NSString *urlLink = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://tdcctv.data.one.gov.hk/, %@!", picName];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlLink];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    self.testingPic.image = image;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [getPic obtainPic:@"H422F2.JPG"];
}
```

Comment: What is the problem or question?

Comment: Is `getPic` ever assigned a value? Also, try: `[self obtainPic:@"H422F2.JPG"];`

Comment: **Obj-C does not have function**

Comment: eat this :) http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: Objective C does have functions.  Objective C is a superset of C, and C has functions, therefore Objective C has functions.

Comment: @ValentinRadu: It's not rhetoric, it's an important technical difference.  Yes, people should learn the difference between methods and functions.  But it is incorrect to say that functions do not exist.

Comment: @Dietrich which would be fine if Anoop had said anything remotely close to "functions don't exist."  He said Objective-C doesn't have functions, which can be taken to mean Objective-C didn't add functions to the C-language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have an error in the construction of the URL, change this line:

```
NSString *urlLink = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://tdcctv.data.one.gov.hk/, %@!", picName];
```

for:

```
NSString *urlLink = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://tdcctv.data.one.gov.hk/%@", picName];
```

doing this I get this image:

[image]

**EDIT**:

you also have an error when calling the method `obtainPic`, change `[getPic obtainPic:@"H422F2.JPG"];` with:

```
[self obtainPic:@"H422F2.JPG"];
```

Comment: But after I change this line, I still cannot see the image in the simulator. What do think other than this error. Thanks.

Comment: you have another error in the `viewDidLoad` method, I edit the question to add it and the solution

Comment: Really thanks for your answer that is useful and the problem is solved. But why the problem is getPic (id type) change to self, what is rationale behind? If you feel free, please explain more to me.

Comment: you should read more about Objective-C and iOS programming, those are really basic concepts, this http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html could be a good starting point

Comment: I have not finish to read all of them. But really thanks!

Comment: it have been a pleasure to helps you, I also recommend you this blog http://www.raywenderlich.com, in the tutorial section you can find a lot off interesting and up to date articles